# How do I calculate sample size so I can be confident that the sample mean approximates the population mean?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

Unfortunately, it's a long while since I did statistics and despite reading & research I'm not 'confident' as to how to calculate this correctly.

I would like to know the smallest sample size required in order to have a given confidence level that the sample mean would be with a given % of the population mean.

Whilst arbitrary, the following would be known (can be calculated):

- population size
- population mean
- population standard deviation

Sampling would be without replacement.

Distribution is normal.

For example, for a population of 1,000,000 with a mean of 0.90 and a population standard deviation of 1.32 I would need a sample n to be 99% confident that the sample mean is within 1% of the population mean.

I'm interested in understanding the formula as I have to solve this many times for different populations, different confidence levels, and different margins of error. Thank you.

Comment: see [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For example, for a population of 1,000,000 with a mean of 0.90 and a population standard deviation of 1.32 I would need a sample n to be 99% confident that the sample mean is within 1% of the population mean.

Okay.

> Sampling would be without replacement.

With a million in the population?

<strike>To a first approximation, it doesn't matter enough to be worth worrying about</strike>

Actually, turns out in this case it does. I'll do it both without replacement and with. With replacement is simpler, and I do it first.

> Distribution is normal.

Don't need it. The sample size will be large enough that with the other assumptions, only really strongly non-normal distributions will have any impact.

Can we assume independence (apart from the effect of sampling without replacement)? e.g. sampling completely at random? I'll take it that we can.

$\mu = 0.90$

$\sigma = 1.32$

Want 'to be 99% confident that the sample mean is within 1% of the population mean'.

i.e. Find $n$ such that $P(|\bar{x}-\mu| < .01\mu) = 0.99$

$\bar{x}-\mu \sim N(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$

99% of a normal distribution is within 2.576  s.d.'s of the population mean (this figure is gettable from normal tables, or using a function in a program. I used R)
`
Thus I need $2.576 \times \sigma/\sqrt{n} < 0.01 \mu = 0.009$

Hence $2.576^2 \sigma^2/n < 0.009^2$

Hence $2.576^2 \sigma^2 < n \times 0.009^2$

Or $n > (2.576 \times 1.32/0.009)^2 = 142742.9$

So if $n$ is about 142700, (the means and sd's and normal table values were only accurate to about the same number of figures - only the first 3-4 digits will be meaningful) then the required probability statement should hold.

If we allow for the 'without replacement' the sample size would reduce about 14% percent (google for *finite population correction* to the variance); other factors are likely to affect you by more than a couple of percent (like not having perfectly random sampling, for one example)

---

Let's look at the without replacement case using the finite population correction now.

The finite population correction multiplies the variance by a factor $f = \frac{N-n}{N-1} = 1-\frac{n-1}{N-1}$.

Some people approximate this by $1 -\, n/N$, which is easily accurate enough with the large numbers for $n$ and $N$ involved here. However, I'll try to do the first version there.

$2.576^2 \sigma^2 (N-n)/(N-1) < n \times 0.009^2$

$(2.576\sigma/0.009)^2 /(N-1) < n/(N-n) $

$(2.576\sigma/0.009)^2 /(N-1) < 1/[N/n\,\,\,  -1] $

$142743 \times 1000000/1142742 < n$

So (if I did that right), $n > 124912.7$

Or to the accuracy in the normal value, $n$ should be about $124900$.

(assuming the mean and s.d. are actually accurate to at least 4 figures, too)

Calculation check:

Interval half-width =

$(2.576\times 1.32/\sqrt{124900})\sqrt{(1000000-124900)/999999}$

$= 0.00900$

Comment: Thank you so much Glen. I think I follow most of that and will practise with some examples. Given that I told you I was very rusty, how do I represent this in the form 'n = ...."

The equation n = ... will help me test my understanding in Excel.

Thank you again.

Comment: Clair - I screwed up the calculation, sorry, leaving out the 2.576 in later calculation. Please look again. Because of that the finite population correction matters, too.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update & explanation Glen. That is much closer to the answer I was expecting. Just to confirm, this example allows the sample mean to be plus or minus 1% of the population mean?

Comment: Just saw your most recent edits.  The detail you have gone to is wonderful. Thank you.  I am impressed by how far the sample size falls for finite populations. Terrific. Thanks, Clair.

Comment: How far it falls depends on how big a fraction of the population you'd be sampling. If you're only sampling 1% of the population, it makes about 1% difference to the sample size. If you're sampling about 10% of the population, the FPC makes roughly 10% difference to the answer.

Comment: @Glen_b What is the mathematical basis behind of the calculation you're doing? Do you have some reference?

Comment: @RobertSmith Hi Robert, please bu assured that I do not mean to be rude to you or Glen but are you suggesting this is not the correct approach, or that there is another approach?

Comment: @Clair.Gibbon don't be concerned on my account. You should ask such questions.

Comment: @RobertSmith Which calculation - the with replacement or the without replacement?

Comment: @Glen_b With replacement. The part starting with $P(|\bar{x}-\mu| < .01\mu) = 0.99$. I have tried to find this type of problem in books or posts but usually authors don't take the total population into account. Therefore, they infer population samples based on a couple of simple formulas without much explanation depending on known variance or proportion of $\bar{x}$.

Comment: @RobertSmith In the case the OP described, the variance was known, and even a population mean was given. Using the CLT ($n$>100000 after all), $\bar{x}-\mu$ is normal with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2/n$ when sampling with replacement. The calculation is straightforward manipulation of normal areas.

Comment: @RobertSmith Even without known $\sigma^2$, one could invoke either Slutsky or the convergence of the $t$ to the normal to produce a normal interval based off an $s$ based from a decently sized sample, or use a t-interval for a small one. Similarly, without a known $\mu$, one could base an interval off a sample there as well (taking into account the effect of uncertainty in the estimate), or find ways to solve (perhaps numerically) a more complex formula with $\mu$ occurring in two places.

Comment: @RobertSmith Lastly, one can always try a range of possible values for the parameters and proceed from a position of caution - such as picking the largest resulting sample size in the set of possibilities.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, I mean that most of the procedures I have seen, don't take this approach with or without known variance and involve an explicit margin of error. Can you give me a reference to a formal explanation of what leads to manipulation of normal areas?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, I have tried to reproduce your answer for the sample size in Excel, substituting into your formula (2.576 * 1.32 / 0.009 ) ^ 2. I get an answer 142,742.9 - and I just can't figure what I've done wrong. :( Thanks for your effort & time.

Comment: @RobertSmith I don't really know a reference. Well, *a reference* of sorts would be [this text](http://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php) (2nd Ed). If you combine eq 4.4 and 4.15, you get the form of CI I used, and the only other thing to do is add the condition that the interval half-width (margin of error, radius) is $\leq 0.01 \mu$.

Comment: @Clair.Gibbon You may not have done anything wrong; the z-value I typed in was rounded off to 4 significant figures, so the answer has *at best* 4 figure accuracy. Since I computed in R, the value in memory may not have been exactly that; or I may simply have typed the final answer wrong. I'll redo it from scratch using the numbers given (which might end up less accurate, but more reproducible).

Comment: @Clair.Gibbon calculations redone. Hopefully these reproduce to more than 3 or 4 significant figures

Comment: @Clair.Gibbon Thanks a lot. By the way, that book looks great.

Comment: @Glen_b Perfect Glen. It appears to have just been a rounding issue.

Comment: @RobertSmith Not sure which book you refer to?

Comment: @Clair.Gibbon The one you linked to: http://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php

Comment: @RobertSmith I'm pretty certain I didn't link to this book but I'm glad you did :) - it looks like a great way to improve my own understanding. Thanks.

Comment: @Clair.Gibbon Right!! I think I misread the name. I was referring to Glen_b. Thanks Glen!